# Implications of renaming sql server 2000 instance

Tags: replication, sql-server

I have a sql server 2000 of which I want to replicate the data to a sql server 2008.  However the output from select @@servername and select serverproperty('servername') on the 2000 server are different and that prevents replication.  There is a process to resolve this at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818334 .  Has anyone done this?  What implications are there for following this process?  Any 'gotchas' that need to be guarded against?  My 2000 server is a lone production server...very scary.  Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix, non invasive. The dropserver/addserver commands really only affect replication, so you will be fine with running them.

Also, this is not renaming the instance, only what it looks like to SQL replication. It sounds like the server had a name change in the past after SQL was installed. That's what causes your queries to return different values.

Comment: Yes, the original db was named something like databaseTemp, which shows up in @@servername.  We use it as something like database (I'm not putting the real name of the instance out of healthy paranoia).  I need the @@servername to be as serverproperty('servername').